# Error in loading SecondActivity after splashscreen

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm facing an issue regarding intent to my SecondActivity, the main activity is the splash screen which has a progressbar. The progressbar intervals loads fine and when it  comes to switching to the next part on moving on to the the secondactivity, i get some errors which are not traceable and are real hectic. Here's my Second Activity's code:

```
package com.example.waleedmalik.computerparts;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ToggleButton tb;
Button btn;
public static boolean tbflag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    tb = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tbflag = tb.isChecked();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
       GameActivity.class);

     startActivity(in);

    }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you add your second Activity in manifest file?

Comment: Post your log details.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>

Comment: 08-31 15:39:06.934    2617-2617/com.example.waleedmalik.computerparts E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.waleedmalik.computerparts, PID: 2617
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.waleedmalik.computerparts/com.example.waleedmalik.computerparts.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: please post your activity_second xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the button initialization like this:

as

`btn = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);`

line to

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friends especially maciej and Hassan Usman,  it worked after this change :-) really appreciate it!